# How to connect to remote MySQL where it is disable on hosting server?

Tags: mysql, remote-connections

I have a website and a windows application that use the same database on a hosting server.
Recently the hosting company disabled remote connection to MySQL from 3rd party applications (such as my windows app).

In this case, how can I connect my application to this database? Is there any way for it?

Comment: which hosting provider are you with? Have you tried googling if they offer the feature? For example i'm with a company called Netvirtue and they offer a guide to enable SSH or Mysql Remote access (https://kb.netvirtue.com.au/index.php?action=artikel&cat=3&id=43&artlang=en)

Answer (score 0):

You could make some kind of API through your web site. Or perhaps tunneling will work, but if your hoster does not want other apps to connect, I reckon tunneling is also out of the question.

Comment: They told me I have to create an intermediate PHP script for it. But I could not understand what they are talking about exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSH available, you may be able to use an *SSH tunnel*. This solution is best for interactive use; you'll have to create the tunnel each time you want to use the application.

Using OpenSSH on the command line:

```
ssh you@webhost -L 3306:localhost:3306
```

Using the graphical SSH client [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), you can go to this node in the settings:

- Connection

  - SSH

    - Tunnels

And add a forward by filling `3306` in the "Source port", and `localhost:3306` in the "Destination", then clicking the "Add" button.

Now you should be able to connect your application to `localhost:3306` and the connection will be passed through to `webhost:3306`.

Comment: I have not access to SSH